# Set up a function to filter through a logical matrix for results across all columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Have been trying to set up a probability space with multiple combinations and want to filter any outcomes that include a specific result and create a subset to find the probability of these.

I  am currently using the prob package to build the probability space, after which I've tried from the subset function to filter from the dplyr package. I just want to know if there's a simple way of creating the subset where one of the outcomes exists.

This is a simplified version of the probspace I'm working with.

```
l<-c('a','b','c','d','e','f')
m<-urnsamples(l,3,FALSE,FALSE)
n<-probspace(m, makespace = TRUE)
```

After this point is where the issue with subsets begins.
Would appreciate any alternatives to building the probspace in simpler ways.